# MediaWiki Extension:Math raw tags

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Installed per [these](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/mediawiki/math) instructions which enables the extension with `mwenext Math.php`, however, raw tags are being displayed with basic example (`<math>0</math>`). The troubleshooting [page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Troubleshooting_math_display_errors#Raw_.3Cmath.3E.3C.2Fmath.3E_Tags) advises to check that `$wgUseTeX = true;` is in LocalSettings, though it is already there per the instructions. Help is most appreciated.

**texvc checked:**

```
texvc /home/wiki/tmp /home/wiki/math "y=x+2" iso-8859-1 "rgb 1.0 1.0 1.0"
Cdaa63ef966cc412541190bc8794731de<i>y</i> = <i>x</i> + 2<mi>y</mi><mo>=</mo><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn>-
```

**LocalSettings.php**

```
# Math engine
$wgUseTeX = true;
$wgUploadPath = "/images";
$wgUploadDirectory = "images";
$wgMathPath = "{$wgUploadPath}/math";
$wgMathDirectory = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/math";
$wgTmpDirectory = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/tmp";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the raw tags, that means the extension is [not enabled](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extensions_FAQ#How_do_I_enable_an_extension.3F). You can verify on the `Special:Version` page. (Note, you probably need to force reparsing of the page for extension changes to take effect - see [action=purge](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Purge).